# Tensorflow unexpectedly caching sub-graph results

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm currently trying to make an augmentation class for TF like so:

```
    class Augmentations:

        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            # Some Global Kwargs Define Here
            self.transforms = tf.eye(3)

            self.img_height = kwargs['img_height']
            self.img_width = kwargs['img_width']

        def _generate_random(self, shape, seed, minval, maxval):
            return tf.random_uniform(shape=shape,
                                     minval=minval,
                                     maxval=maxval,
                                     seed=seed,
                                     dtype=tf.float32)

        def rotate(self, seed, max_angle):
            random_rotation_value = self._generate_random([1], seed, 0., max_angle)
            rotation_matrix = tf.contrib.image.angles_to_projective_transforms(
                                random_rotation_value,
                                self.img_height,
                                self.img_width)

            rotation_matrix = tf.reshape(tf.concat([rotation_matrix, [[1.]]], axis=1),
                                         [3, 3])

            self.transforms = tf.matmul(self.transforms, rotation_matrix)
            return self


        def apply(self, img):
            t = tf.reshape(tf.matmul(self.transforms[0],
                                     self.transforms[1]),
                           [1, 9])[0, :8]
            return tf.contrib.image.transform(img, t)
```

I've tried both the `dataset.map` and `tf.map_fn` with both returning a consistent transform, i.e.:

```
augment = Augment(**kwargs).rotate(None, 30).shear(None, 30)
dataset = dataset.map(augment.apply, num_parallel_calls=10)
```

and

```
augment = Augment(**kwargs).rotate(None, 30).shear(None, 30)
dataset = tf.map_fn(augment.apply)
```

Both of these calls return different images with the same transforms applied.

The only way to return the images with random transforms is call the transform in the `map()`:

```
dataset = dataset.map(Augment(**kwargs).rotate(None, 30).shear(None, 30).apply, num_parallel_calls=10)
```

or move all of the random numbers into the `apply()`.

Does the placement of `random_*()` calls matter in TF, I was under the idea that the placement would not matter, does it only matter for the `map_fn`?

Answer (score 0):

This is intended behavior because all the calls to your `apply` method share the same `tf.random_uniform` operation. When you invoke `session.run` this random operation is evaluated once and its result is used for all elements.

Invoking `tf.random_uniform` in apply makes a difference because you will create multiple random ops and each one will produce a different random sequence. It is basically the difference between:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.random_uniform((1,))
y = tf.stack([x * tf.constant(1.0), x * tf.constant(1.0)])
y.eval() 
# Prints
#   array([[ 0.67649043],
#          [ 0.67649043]], dtype=float32)
# because there is only one random operation in the graph and it is evaluated once.
```

and

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
y = tf.stack([tf.random_uniform((1,)) * tf.constant(1.0), tf.random_uniform((1,)) * tf.constant(1.0)])
y.eval()
# Prints
# array([[ 0.08824277],
#        [ 0.4801079 ]], dtype=float32)
# because there are two random operations in the graph and each yields a different value when evaluated
```

It is pretty fundamental that tensorflow evaluates an op at most once per `session.run()` call (assuming it is not in a `while` loop or similar).